# Using nullable DateTime in Remote Validation gives null (ASP .Net MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, datepicker

I have a model with a nullable DateTime property.

The date does not need to be entered, hence the nullable type. If it *IS* entered, though, it should be validated to lie forward in time.

Using Remote Validation on the property however, always gives ***null*** as an in-parameter in my validation method, even if the datepicker-field contains a value using the correct format. How can I get it to try the value from my input field?

The datepicker calender is limited to not be able to pick past dates. But you are still able to input a date manually. Doing so triggers the validation but always with a null value as in-parameter. I have a similar function where the DateTime is not nullable and it works correctly.

**MODEL**

```
[Remote("CheckDateNotInPast", "Validation", ErrorMessage = @"The date must lie forward in time.")]
        public DateTime? Deadline { get; set; }
```

---

**VALIDATION CONTROLLER**

```
//The date parameter here is always null, even when the field contains a correct value to check.

public JsonResult CheckDateNotInPast(DateTime? date)
        {
            return Json((date == null || DateTime.UtcNow.Date <= date.Date), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

---

**VIEW**

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Deadline, new { @placeholder = (Model.Deadline == null ? "YYYY-MM-DD" : Model.Deadline.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")), @class = "form-control", @id = "datepicker" })
            <span class="nais-error-text">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Deadline)</span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property is named `Deadline`, therefor the parameter in your controller method must match. Change it to

```
public JsonResult CheckDateNotInPast(DateTime? deadline)
```

and it will be correctly passed.

As a side note, you can use a conditional validation attribute (such as a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThanOrEqualTo]`, or you can easily create your own) so that your get client and server side validation without need the extra overhead of an ajax call (which after the initial validation, will be done on every `.keyup()` event by default).

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. I was thinking of reusing it for other similar properties but didn't know about the naming convetion.

I also checked out foolproof. It seems like the perfect thing to use for all these date validations I have. Thank you!

Comment: You can also refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) if you want to learn how to create you own validation attributes